# How to fetch Multiline textbox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" id="txtHelpText" />
```

added multiple times in a web page.

Want to fetch its value using jquery -

```
$(this).find('input[id*=txtHelpText]').val();
```

When I remove the `TextMode="MultiLine"`, then it works as expected and providing value but not with Multiline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `TextMode="MultiLine"`, the output will be a `textarea`, instead of `input`. So you must use this:

```
$(this).find('textarea[id*=txtHelpText]').val();
```

Comment: Checking the same.. will reply soon